# Where is the source code for JUnit hosted currently?

Tags: junit

The [main site](http://junit.org/) says it is now hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit), however that page now 404s. [A search for "JUnit"](https://github.com/search?q=junit&type=Repositories&ref=simplesearch) does not return anything that looks like it's the main project and it is not listed as one of [Kent Beck's repositories](https://github.com/KentBeck?tab=repositories).

The [SourceForge site](http://junit.sourceforge.net/) also points you to the GitHub site. It also says
"`We are deprecating our SourceForge installation.`" Also, the latest version hosted on SourceForge is 4.10 while the last released was 4.11.

So, where is the current source code for JUnit hosted?

Comment: It is hosted on GitHub: https://github.com/junit-team/junit

Comment: It's the first result when you [search for "junit"](https://github.com/search?q=junit&type=Repositories)... (the 1,300+ stars is a good hint it's the main repo.)

Comment: I misread that as "junit-team" to be the name of the library not the account that owns it. You'll see that I did search for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The source code for JUnit is hosted at GitHub:

http://github.com/junit-team/junit

Previously it was hosted by a member: [KentBeck](https://github.com/KentBeck), but now it is hosted by a GitHub-company: [junit-team](https://github.com/junit-team), and that's the reason of the 404 you are receiving (the repo was transfered from member to company).

As you noticed it, they didn't updated their site with this information.

Comment: I saw "junit-team" and assumed it was a plugin for a team based tool to use with JUnit. I guess I should have noticed that was the owner and not the name of the tool itself.

Answer (score 0):

For some time jUnit has been hosted at github: https://github.com/junit-team/junit